# Natbib puts reference data one line per item

Tags: line-breaking, natbib

I'm using:

```
\documentclass[oneside,article,openbib,12pt,titlepage]{memoir}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib} % Better bibliography support
\bibpunct{(}{)}{,}{a}{,}{,}
```

in the preamble of my document and

```
\backmatter
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\bibliographystyle{chicago}   
\bibliography{listb,mybib}
```

in the body of the file. But a typical formatted reference is:

> Freely, I. (1997).
>   A small paper.
>   The journal of small papers -1. to appear.

I've tried other non-`natbib` styles (e.g., `regstud`), and the reference flows and wraps as it should. So how does one get `natbib` to do the same?

Also, how does one get `natbib` to include the authors' entire first names?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The `openbib` option is responsible of the formatting you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, the bibliography output you report looks like it comes from the `unsrt` bibliography style, and definitely not like it's produced with the `chicago` bibliography style.

Please note that `natbib` package is a citation management package, one that lets you use employ both numeric and author-year type citation methods. (Using the author-year method is greatly simplified by using the commands `\citet` and `\citep` that are provided by the `natbib` package). However, the file `chicago.bst` is *not* part of the `natbib` package.

You may want to check why you have the `openbib` option among the options you specify for the `\documentclass` command. The `openbib` option used to be of relevance for LaTeX2.09-type files that had to be compiled in compatibility mode under the LaTeX2e format, but otherwise it should no longer be needed. Indeed, it would appear that specifying the `openbib` option creates some interference with `natbib` because it seems to load the `unsrt` bibliography style file automatically (and, worse, does so in a way that overrides your specification of `chicago` as the bibliography style file). Hence, do check if you really need the `openbib` option.

Regarding your final question: Whether the full first name of each author and/or editor is shown in the bibliography does not depend on the choice of citation manager package, but on the bibliography style file (.bst) you specify.

Comment: Yes, I was using \citep. Getting rid of openbib solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Mico. Yes, I used \citep. Getting rid of openbib solved the problem. I don't remember why I added it. I think to solve a 2.09 conversion error. As for your last point, I'm a bit confused. Can I specify _any_ .bst file with natbib? I thought natbib needs its own .bst files. I have a hard time figuring out what style file does exactly what I need. Alas, few style file names give a clue about the format unless you're already familiar with the style. (E.g., "alpha") Is there a gallery of samples somewhere? Thanks again.