# BibTeX reference formats in JabRef and LyX

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, lyx, jabref

I am using JabRef for my references. I export them as a `.bib` file and import them into LyX.  They are all sorted correctly and referenced fine in the text. However, when I look in the actual bibliography section of my paper they look pretty ugly: some have URL's, some have extra spaces that look unprofessional.  Is there a way to make all of the references that are printed have the same fields and format?

MWE:

Here are two bibtex entries:

```
@ARTICLE{ADRIAN2008,
  author = {Adrian, Tobias And Rosenberg, Joshua},
  title = {Stock Returns and Volatility: Pricing the Short-Run and Long-Run
    Components of Market Risk},
  journal = {The Journal of Finance},
  year = {2008},
  volume = {63},
  pages = {2997--3030},
  number = {6},
  doi = {10.1111/j.1540-6261.2008.01419.x},
  issn = {1540-6261},
  owner = {home},
  publisher = {Blackwell Publishing Inc},
  timestamp = {2013.01.31},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/j.1540-6261.2008.01419.x}
}

@ARTICLE{Ang2006,
  author = {Ang, Andrew and Chen, Joseph and Xing, Yuhang},
  title = {Downside Risk},
  journal = {Review of Financial Studies},
  year = {2006},
  volume = {19},
  pages = {1191-1239},
  number = {4},
  abstract = {Economists have long recognized that investors care differently about
downside losses versus upside gains. Agents who place greater weight
on downside risk demand additional compensation for holding stocks
with high sensitivities to downside market movements. We show that
the cross section of stock returns reflects a downside risk premium
of approximately 6% per annum. Stocks that covary strongly with the
market during market declines have high average returns. The reward
for beasring downside risk is not simply compensation for regular
market beta, nor is it explained by coskewness or liquidity risk,
or by size, value, and momentum characteristics. (<I>JEL</I> C12,
C15, C32, G12)},
  doi = {doi:10.1093/rfs/hhj035},
  owner = {home},
  timestamp = {2013.01.31},
  url =     {http://www.ingentaconnect.com/content/oup/revfin/2006/00000019/00000004/art01191}
}
```

The LyX file:

```
%% LyX 2.0.5.1 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[11pt,openbib]{article}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1in,rmargin=1in}
\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{C:/Users/home/Desktop/test}

\end{document}
```

It does look like part of the problem is that some entries have more information than others: ie URL's, etc. Do I have to edit each one or can BibTeX be run to only display certain aspects of an entry to make them all the same?

Comment: Normally ``bibtex`` should take care of most of this stuff by itself. Could you provide us with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), please?

Comment: Quite often, ugly references are a sign of missing fields in the .bib entry.

Comment: hi guys. just added the mwe. it looks way better than my current big doc. i'll see if missing fields are the problem but ALL the references are ugly so i don't think that's it

Comment: Can you post a small PDF image showing a couple of of references?  Normally, to disable certain fields in bibtex, I think the only option is to edit .bst style file that you are using.  Unless of course the style has options that you can set in the preamble.  Check natbib documentation, if you are using natbib.  Failing all of this, consider using biblatex.  It has extensive options for disabling fields.

Comment: i am using natbib in fact. i don't have a .bst file though.. is that generated automatically by bibtex or do i need style files that i somehow import into lyx?

Comment: got it. the key was to use a style file. i ended up throwing in the harvard style file and things look good now.. no more random fields and stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The style of the references is not much depending on the data in the `.bib` file (or a program like JabRef). The main factor is the chosen bibliography style of your document. It determines which fields are shown.

Suggestions to improve the looks:

- If URLs occur in your document (e.g. in the references) you can add

  ```
  \usepackage{url}
  ```

  to the preamble (in LyX `Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble`). Then long URLs like in your second reference will have a proper line break. Not necessary if package "hyperref" is used, see [Forcing linebreaks in \url](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3033/forcing-linebreaks-in-url/3034#3034).
- If "extra spaces that look unprofessional" refer to the line breaks after every field in the references then removing the document option `openbib` helps (in LyX `Document > Settings... > Document Class`); see [Natbib puts reference data one line per item](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44991/natbib-puts-reference-data-one-line-per-item) or [Custom references page with additional line breaks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56628/custom-references-page-with-additional-line-breaks).
- Of course, a bibliography style different from "plainnat" can be choosen in LyX by a right click on "BibTeX Generated Bibliography" and then "Settings...".
- Nevertheless, a little edit of your `.bib` file (with JabRef) could be done:

  - The URL of "ADRIAN2008" should be cleared since it replicates the DOI entry.
    (In JabRef, an clickable icon with hyperlink is shown for a non-empty URL field. If the URL field is empty but not the DOI field then still a clickable icon is shown. It provides the hyperlink `http://dx.doi.org/<DOI field value>` automatically.)
  - [Dashes: - vs. – vs. —](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3819/dashes-vs-vs): `pages = {1191-1239}` should be `pages = {1191--1239}` for the right length of the dash.
  - `doi = {doi:10.1093/rfs/hhj035}` should be `doi = {10.1093/rfs/hhj035}`.